# How to get the value of a select when using ngValue in Angular unit tests

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test, angular-unit-test, angular-testing-library

In my Angular app I have a `<select>` bound to a reactive form like the following:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="myControlName" id="my-select">
    <option [value]="value" *ngFor="let value of mySelectValues">{{ value }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

At this stage, `mySelectValues` is an array of strings.

I do [component dom testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-basics#component-dom-testing) like this:

```js
it('the select should reflect the form value"', () => {

  // I somehow change the form value to 'ABC' here 
  // and I want to check if the select is correctly showing the change

  const select = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#my-select');
  expect(select.value).toEqual('ABC');
});
```

This works fine. However, at some point, in some selects I needed to have Objects as values instead of plain strings/numbers in some places.

So I've changed my HTML code to use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`:

```html
<option [ngValue]="value" ...
```

At this point, in my test the value of `select.value` is no longer `'ABC'` but becomes something like `'2: ABC'` where `2` is the index of the selected option, then a column + space, then the actual value.

So far I can live with this, just by changing my test to:

```js
expect(select.value).toEqual('2: ABC');
```

And it keeps working. However, in some places, I need to use Objects as values, so `mySelectValues` will be not an array of plain strings/numbers, but an array of objects instead.

For example:

```js
mySelectValues = [
  { name: 'Name 1', value: 'MyTestValue1' },
  { name: 'Name 2', value: 'MyTestValue2' },
];
```

And so changing the HTML like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="myControlName" id="my-select">
    <option [ngValue]="object.value" *ngFor="let object of mySelectValues">{{ object.name }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

The select now works fine with objects. However, my test no longer works because `select.value` is now returning always values like `'2: Object'` because an object is selected and no longer a plain string.

How can I solve this problem?

In other words: given a `<select>` that uses `<option>` with `[ngValue]` bound to objects, how can I get the selected value of the `<select>` (accessing it via the DOM like in my original test case) ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?